# Change routing mode

Tags: c, contiki, rpl

In RPL storing mode, how can a packet be delivered according to the default route instead of the route in the routing table? Is it possible to modify a control bit in an IP packet?

Comment: If no other route matches the packet's destination address, the default route is used. I'm not sure I understand your question, can you explain more?

Comment: I mean, there is a route matches the packet's destination in routing table. But I want to transmit with the default route .

Comment: Is there a control bit to do with it?

Comment: No, as far as I know. More complex rules for policy routing are not implemented in Contiki. Just the default rule "select the route with the longest matching prefix".

Comment: I have tried to delete the route matches the packet's destination in routing table and then add a default route to the neighbor. But when I do the simulation, the packet does not transmit to the neighbor.